# MySQL table store large value in exponential format

Tags: php, mysql

While inserting into mysql table it convert 1000000000 to 1e+09 and so on.

insertion is doing by **INSERT** query

> field datatype is float

and

> DB engine is InnoDB

this is live db on Debian server though same **INSERT** query save 1000000000 correctly when db on Amazon server . Very strange :(

Comment: And what do you use to display the data? PHP script? Some sort of a GUI? Might it be that it's actually the software you use for the display that converts MySQL value to scientific notation?

Comment: PHP script only as I tagged with my question :)

Answer (score 2):

`1e+9` is `1000000000`. Use `number_format()` to display the value in normal notation.

Comment: but friend i got 1e+9 not 1000000000. I tried and it says:
Message: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given

Comment: but thanks it give me a clue to solve in combination with floatval()

Comment: It seems there's some additional processing going on after the value is fetched from database. Maybe you're using some database access library?